# An information of a pink bar: flags

Tags: discussion, support, design, flagging

I was just wondering why some flags are highlighted with a pink background? I only have two pink ones. What's the reason? Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pink background means that the flagged question, answer or comment has been deleted.

Comment: Thank you very very very much. Now I have understood.